# long for-loop crush my android application

Tags: java, android, for-loop, lag

I've tried to solve this issue through searching for a similar problem,
however I'm sorry for my question it might be newbie question. The problem is whenever I start a long loop it's just crush!

For example, if I had `TextView` and I want set text of 0 and doing loop to increase the value up to 10 for example it will crash!  Even though with thread it still crashes.

Here's my code :

```
package com.example.mathexercises;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class level1 extends Activity {
    TextView QuestionLable;
    TextView TimeLable;
    int QandA[][];
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.level1);
        QuestionLable = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Level1QuestionLable);
        TimeLable     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Level1Time);
        QandA =(int[][]) savedInstanceState.get("ArrayOfExer");

        int sum=0;
        String Qformated="";
        TimeLable.setText("Started !!");
        for (int i = 0; QandA !=null && i<QandA.length; i++) {
            try {
                Qformated = "" + QandA[i][0];
                switch (QandA[i][1]) {
                case -1:
                    Qformated += " +";
                    break;
                case -2:
                    Qformated += " -";
                    break;
                case -3:
                    Qformated += " X";
                    break;
                case -4:
                    Qformated += " /";
                    break;

                }

                Qformated += " " + QandA[i][2];
                sum+=QandA[i][3];
                QuestionLable.setText(Qformated);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

logCat

```
06-04 01:24:42.875: D/dalvikvm(24925): Late-enabling CheckJNI
06-04 01:24:43.275: D/libEGL(24925): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
06-04 01:24:43.300: D/libEGL(24925): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
06-04 01:24:43.305: D/libEGL(24925): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
06-04 01:24:43.365: D/(24925): Device driver API match
06-04 01:24:43.365: D/(24925): Device driver API version: 10
06-04 01:24:43.365: D/(24925): User space API version: 10 
06-04 01:24:43.365: D/(24925): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
06-04 01:24:43.425: D/OpenGLRenderer(24925): Enabling debug mode 0
06-04 01:24:43.485: E/SensorManager(24925): thread start
06-04 01:24:43.500: D/SensorManager(24925): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@429e4a30
06-04 01:24:50.705: D/AndroidRuntime(24925): Shutting down VM
06-04 01:24:50.705: W/dalvikvm(24925): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d692a0)
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mathexercises/com.example.mathexercises.level1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925):    at com.example.mathexercises.level1.onCreate(level1.java:26)
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
06-04 01:24:50.715: E/AndroidRuntime(24925):    ... 11 more
```

*thank you for your time

Comment: "...  it's just crush !" That's not helpful at all. Please, post the stacktrace.

Comment: Also, you should not be doing things like setting the same item's text view 10,000. Why not just set it once to the correct value? On top of that your doing this on the main UI thread.

Comment: will my program has array[10][30] which is Questions and answers and i have to loop all my Array and each time i have to show the Question then sleep for 10sec ... so i've post something similar to my issue ,, which i've test where is the issue and it's was about the loop it's not showing to to the user how is it increasing !

Comment: Its throwing a null pointer exception. Are you sure the get instance state is returning something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the first run, `null` is passed via `onCreate()`. You should check for `null`:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null)
{
    QandA =(int[][]) savedInstanceState.get("ArrayOfExer");
}
else
{
    // QandA might be initialized as empty array here
}
```

Comment: that's correct because it's null ,, but why savedInstanceState is null it should be contains my data send from other activity ?

Comment: @EngHamoud The other activity sends the data via the intent.

Answer (score 2):

Your logcat shows that you're getting a NullPointer exception.

Since you haven't included line numbers in your source code, it's tough to tell exactly where, but I'm guessing that `QandA` is null, i.e. `savedInstanceState.get("ArrayOfExer");` is returning null.

You shouldn't do any long-running tasks in onCreate, as it will likely cause your Activity to timeout during startup. Do stuff like this on a background thread if it's going to take any significant amount of time.

Oh, and by the way, you should probably read up on Java naming conventions.
Class names typically begin with upper-case characters, member variables and method names begin with lower-case characters.

Sticking to the conventions makes it easier for others to read your code.

Also, I hate to 'pile on', but you should *never* mess with loop variables while in the loop.

```
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            i--;
        }
```

is a truly Bad Thing (TM) to be doing.